# Why is typeof used here?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin

Im making an app on android and I kind of got used to saying `StartActivity(typeof(SomeActivity));` but I never really understood why you need to use `typeof` instead of just writing `StartActivity(SomeActivity)`

Can anyone explain it to me?

Answer (score 0):

In first case it will be Type in the second it will be class. This is diffrient things.

Answer (score 0):

Probably your call to the function depends on the typeof(SomeActivity) and not the SomeActivity itself. Think of SomeActivity itself able to take many values while being of the same type. So your condition to the calling function just depends on the type and not the instance of the value. By the way, this uses the compile time info to construct the other function as opposed to using SomeActivity.GetType() which uses runtime type.

Comment: PRobably right, it probably needs to check if `OnCreate` is overridden